# How to access the new Gmail API from my Android app?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am trying to access the new [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview) (announced 25.06.2014) from my Android app in order to return all e-mail messages in a certain users's account. I am developing the app in Eclipse using the ADT plug-in. 
What I have done so far:

- I registered the application in the Google Developers Console 
  (link: **console.developers.google.com/project**).
- I have implemented the Google+ Sign-in button (link: **developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in**). 
  The Google+ Sign-In button authenticates the user and manages the OAuth 2.0 flow, which simplifies your integration with the Google APIs.
- I added the additional scope 'https:// www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly' to the Google+ Authorization, for accessing the Gmail API, as specified in 
  (Link: **developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list**).

At this point I have an initialized GoogleApiClient object.

The GoogleApiClient object wraps a ServiceConnection (link: **developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html**) to Google Play services. The GoogleApiClient object is used to communicate with the Google+ API and becomes functional after the asynchronous connection has been established with the service, indicating that:

- Google Play services is running on the device and the app Activity has successfully bound the service connection,
- the user has selected an account that they wish to use with the app, and
- the user's account has granted the permissions that the app is requesting.

How do I proceed from here to getting all the messages with this [httprequest](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list)? 
 I tried accessing the Gmail API at this point but I recieve Authentication error 401: Login required, even thought the Google+ login was successful, and I successfully returned a list of User's circles.

EDIT: SecondActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.People;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.People.LoadPeopleResult;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.PersonBuffer;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Users;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Users.Messages.GmailImport;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailRequest;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.application.PeopleAdapter;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.interfaces.GetMessages;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.tasks.GetMessagesTask;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.util.MyClass;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.util.exception.FaceClientException;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.util.model.Face;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.util.model.Guess;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.util.model.Photo;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.util.response.PhotoResponse;
import mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.util.response.PhotoResponseImpl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SecondActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GetMessages, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
    ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>, View.OnClickListener {

  private static final String TAG = "android-plus-quickstart";

  private static final int STATE_DEFAULT = 0;
  private static final int STATE_SIGN_IN = 1;
  private static final int STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 2;

  private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
  private static final int MY_ACTIVITYS_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE=045;

  private static final int DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR = 0;

  private static final String SAVED_PROGRESS = "sign_in_progress";

  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
  String name; 

  private PendingIntent mSignInIntent;
  private int mSignInError;
  private SignInButton mSignInButton;
  private Button mSignOutButton;
  private Button mRevokeButton;
  private TextView mStatus;
  private ListView mCirclesListView;
  private ArrayAdapter<String> mCirclesAdapter;
  private ArrayList<String> mCirclesList;

  public Scope gmail=new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
  String scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly";
  String email="email@gmail.com";



@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    name="Team";

    mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
    mRevokeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.revoke_access_button);
    mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_status);
    mCirclesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.circles_list);

    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSignOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRevokeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mCirclesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mCirclesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, R.layout.circle_member, mCirclesList);
    mCirclesListView.setAdapter(mCirclesAdapter);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      mSignInProgress = savedInstanceState
          .getInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, STATE_DEFAULT);

    }

    mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
  }



private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .addScope(gmail)
        .build();
  }

@Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask();
  }



@Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, mSignInProgress);
  }



@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
          switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.sign_in_button:
            mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signing_in);
            resolveSignInError();
            break;
          case R.id.sign_out_button:
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            break;
          case R.id.revoke_access_button:
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            break;
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");

    getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask();

    mSignInButton.setEnabled(false);
    mSignOutButton.setEnabled(true);
    mRevokeButton.setEnabled(true);

    // Retrieve some profile information. This is OK
    Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    String klient=mGoogleApiClient.toString();


    mStatus.setText(String.format(
        getResources().getString(R.string.signed_in_as),
        currentUser.getDisplayName()));


    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
        .setResultCallback(this);

    GetMessagesTask task = new GetMessagesTask(
            SecondActivity.this, name, mGoogleApiClient);
        task.setDelegate(SecondActivity.this);
        task.execute();

    // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;

  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might
    // be returned in onConnectionFailed.
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
        + result.getErrorCode());

    if (mSignInProgress != STATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
      mSignInIntent = result.getResolution();
      mSignInError = result.getErrorCode();

      if (mSignInProgress == STATE_SIGN_IN) {
        // STATE_SIGN_IN indicates the user already clicked the sign in button
        // so we should continue processing errors until the user is signed in
        // or they click cancel.
        resolveSignInError();
      }
    }

    onSignedOut();
  }


  private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mSignInIntent != null) {

      try {
        mSignInProgress = STATE_IN_PROGRESS;
        startIntentSenderForResult(mSignInIntent.getIntentSender(),
            RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
      } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sign in intent could not be sent: "
            + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Attempt to connect to
        // get an updated ConnectionResult.
        mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

      }
    } else {
      // Google Play services wasn't able to provide an intent for some
      // error types, so we show the default Google Play services error
      // dialog which may still start an intent if the
      // user can resolve the issue.
      showDialog(DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
    }
  }


  @Override
  public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
    if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
      mCirclesList.clear();
      PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
      try {
          int count = personBuffer.getCount();
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              mCirclesList.add(personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
          }
      } finally {
          personBuffer.close();
      }

      mCirclesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error requesting visible circles: " + peopleData.getStatus());
    }
  }

  private void onSignedOut() {
    // Update the UI to reflect that the user is signed out.
    mSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
    mSignOutButton.setEnabled(false);
    mRevokeButton.setEnabled(false);

    mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);

    mCirclesList.clear();
    mCirclesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason.
    // We call connect() to attempt to re-establish the connection or get a
    // ConnectionResult that we can attempt to resolve.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
  }

  @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
      case DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR:
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(mSignInError)) {
          return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
              mSignInError,
              this,
              RC_SIGN_IN,
              new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services resolution cancelled");
                  mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                  mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                }
              });
        } else {
          return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
              .setMessage(R.string.play_services_error)
              .setPositiveButton(R.string.close,
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services error could not be "
                          + "resolved: " + mSignInError);
                      mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                      mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                    }
                  }).create();
        }
      default:
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
  }




    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           if (requestCode == MY_ACTIVITYS_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE) {
               if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask();
               }
           }
       }


       public void getAndUseAuthTokenBlocking() throws UserRecoverableAuthException, IOException, GoogleAuthException {

              final String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, email, scope);
              String fff="";
        }      


       public void getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask() {

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void>() {


               @Override
               protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   try {
                    getAndUseAuthTokenBlocking();
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                   return null;
               }
           };
           task.execute((Void)null);
       }

    }
```

EDIT 2: LogCat

```
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.GmailLinkGrabberService$getAuthToken.doInBackground(GmailLinkGrabberService.java:104)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at mk.ukim.feit.recognizer.GmailLinkGrabberService$getAuthToken.doInBackground(GmailLinkGrabberService.java:1)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-16 06:44:27.300: E/AndroidRuntime(11875):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: I have successfully implemented Gmail API in my android app. I can help you debug if you provide your code.

Comment: I don't know how to access the gmail account of the logged user, after returning the Google+ circles. Any help? @gitter

Comment: I want to call
`response=service.users().threads().list("me").setQ(query).setPageT`
`oken(pageToken).execute();`
to retrieve a list with all threads matching a query in the user inbox.

Comment: This code implements the same thing: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gitanshu/privly-android/gmail-rest/src/ly/priv/mobile/GmailLinkGrabberService.java
Also, the scope should be "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"

Comment: I tried implementing the code from your link, but can't get it to work. In the new edit above I posted the LogCat error. Thanks for your help @gitter

Comment: This is the line of code where the error occurs 
`GoogleCredential credential = new`
`GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);` @gitter

Comment: have you copied all the required jar files?

Comment: I believe so, I have the following: android-support-v4.jar;
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar; commons-lang-2.6.jar; face4j-core-1.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar; google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar; google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar;
google-api-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar; google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev3-1.18.0-rc.jar; google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar; google-http-client-jackson-1.18.0-rc.jar; google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar; google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar; google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar; httpclient-4.0.1.jar; httpmime-4.0.3.jar; jackson-core-2.1.3.jar; slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar

Comment: See my previous comment @gitter

Comment: @gitter would you be willing to share your code, or some insights at least. I am also trying to implement the new Gmail API in Android, but it is not easy at all since, there are no docs for Android implementation. I am also wonder just how you did it then.

Comment: @Jakob checkout the 4th comment on this thread. I have provided a link of my code. I'll try adding more documentation to it when I get time. But I believe it's easy enough to understand.

Comment: Great! Would you deem this API ready for production use on Android yet. E.i. if it seems to be working good enough for use in published apps?

Comment: Yes, it works very well, I still haven't found any bugs...

Comment: It would be ideal if someone could put up on github a full working demo app - with jar files (or better yet - gradle references).  Anyone have something?

Comment: Hi. I have followed gitter's example. Everything works great except I'm getting a 403 error when trying to get emails. Added the client Id in the api console but still no go. Anyone? Oh yes and used the correct scope as well

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Maybe you can paste here the code where you get the error? @TalMihr

Comment: @gitter I am signing in using a Google+login bu am having difficulties creating a GoogleApiClient object I'm using the following code: `Scope gmailreadonly = new Scope("oauth2:googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(gmailreadonly)
                .build();`

Comment: Added a new answer which will hopefully clarify some of these comments as well as the OP's original inquiry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(Feb 2017)** The [Gmail API](http://developers.google.com/gmail/api) (v1 [launched](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2014/06/introducing-new-gmail-api.html) Jun 2014) is the best way of integrating Gmail functionality into your apps (and preferred over POP/IMAP & SMTP). In order to use this and most other Google APIs from Android, you need to get [the Google APIs Client Library for Android](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/android) (or for more general Java, [the Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java)).

Now for some working samples: here are the [Android quickstart](http://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) & the more general [Java quickstart](http://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java). Having the [Gmail API JavaDocs reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/) at your side isn't a bad idea either. OAuth2 is now the preferred way to perform auth, meaning you'll need code that looks like this, plus the right [scope](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/GmailScopes.html):

```
// Sheets RO scope
private static final String[] SCOPES = {GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY};
    :

// Initialize credentials and service object
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
        getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
        .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

Other than this "setup," the OP has most everything needed to get something working:

1. Having a project in the [developers console](http://console.developers.google.com) & enabled the Gmail API with the SHA1 hash (as described above in the Android quickstart)
2. Implementing OAuth2 with the correct scope(s)
3. Making [the call](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/model/ListThreadsResponse.html) to `ListThreadsResponse listResponse = mService.users().threads().list(user).execute();` -- the quickstart uses `labels()` so you can just change to `threads()`

To learn more about the API, below are 3 videos, the first introducing the API when it launched. If you're not "allergic" to Python, I made the other pair with short but more "real-world" examples using the Gmail API (non-mobile though):

- [Introducing the Gmail API](http://youtu.be/UhdiQmS3kDs)
- [Revolutionizing Email Access with the Gmail API](http://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/btPaP3VnrGr) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/08/accessing-gmail-from-python-plus-bonus.html))
- [Modifying your signature with the Gmail API](http://developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/modifying-email-signatures-with-the-gmail-api.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/12/modifying-email-signatures-with-gmail.html))

It's not mentioned as part of the title, but the 2nd video above features a code sample that accesses thread and messages with the Gmail API.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
// Logcat tag
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

// Profile pic image size in pixels
private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

// Google client to interact with Google API
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
 * from starting further intents.
 */
private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private boolean mSignInClicked;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

    // Button click listeners
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Get user's information
    getProfileInformation();

    // Update the UI after signin
    updateUI(true);

}

/**
 * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
 * */
private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

/**
 * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
 * */
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    updateUI(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Button on click listener
 * */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_sign_in:
        // Signin button clicked
        signInWithGplus();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_sign_out:
        // Signout button clicked
        signOutFromGplus();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
        // Revoke access button clicked
        revokeGplusAccess();
        break;
    }
}

/**
 * Sign-in into google
 * */
private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/**
 * Sign-out from google
 * */
private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Revoking access from google
 * */
private void revokeGplusAccess() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        updateUI(false);
                    }

                });
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
 * */
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

class i use t access gmail api -

```
public class GMail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

private Multipart attachements;

private String fromAddress = "";
private String accountEmail = "";
private String accountPassword = "";
private String smtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String smtpPort = "465"; // 465,587
private String toAddresses = "";
private String mailSubject = "";
private String mailBody = "";

public GMail() {
    attachements = new MimeMultipart();

}

public GMail(String user, String pass) {
    this();
    accountEmail = user;
    accountPassword = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    // props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", smtpPort);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
        session.setDebug(true);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        // create the message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        // fill message
        messageBodyPart.setText(mailBody);
        // add to multipart
        attachements.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // msg.setText(mailBody);
        msg.setSubject(mailSubject);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(toAddresses));
        msg.setContent(attachements);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect(smtpHost, 465, accountEmail, accountPassword);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName("Victim");
    attachements.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

// private String getFormattedDate(Date date) {
// SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
// "EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
// return sdf.format(date);
// }

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(accountEmail, accountPassword);
}

/**
 * Gets the fromAddress.
 * 
 * @return <tt> the fromAddress.</tt>
 */
public String getFromAddress() {
    return fromAddress;
}

/**
 * Sets the fromAddress.
 * 
 * @param fromAddress
 *            <tt> the fromAddress to set.</tt>
 */
public void setFromAddress(String fromAddress) {
    this.fromAddress = fromAddress;
}

/**
 * Gets the toAddresses.
 * 
 * @return <tt> the toAddresses.</tt>
 */
public String getToAddresses() {
    return toAddresses;
}

/**
 * Sets the toAddresses.
 * 
 * @param toAddresses
 *            <tt> the toAddresses to set.</tt>
 */
public void setToAddresses(String toAddresses) {
    this.toAddresses = toAddresses;
}

/**
 * Gets the mailSubject.
 * 
 * @return <tt> the mailSubject.</tt>
 */
public String getMailSubject() {
    return mailSubject;
}

/**
 * Sets the mailSubject.
 * 
 * @param mailSubject
 *            <tt> the mailSubject to set.</tt>
 */
public void setMailSubject(String mailSubject) {
    this.mailSubject = mailSubject;
}

/**
 * Gets the mailBody.
 * 
 * @return <tt> the mailBody.</tt>
 */
public String getMailBody() {
    return mailBody;
}

/**
 * Sets the mailBody.
 * 
 * @param mailBody
 *            <tt> the mailBody to set.</tt>
 */
public void setMailBody(String mailBody) {
    this.mailBody = mailBody;
}
}
```

To use This class -

```
GMail m = new GMail(context.getResources().getString(
                R.string.emailId), context.getResources().getString(
                R.string.pas));
m.setToAddresses("some@example.com,another@some.com");
m.setFromAddress("yourid@gmail.com");
m.setMailSubject(subjectText);
m.setMailBody(bodyText);
```

Comment: OP is trying to access the new Gmail API (announced 25.06.2014), this looks like general SMTP email access.

Comment: Correct. The Gmail API (http://) is now the preferred way of accessing Gmail services, not POP/IMAP nor SMTP. More in my answer to this question.

Comment: This is FALSE advertising. It's using plain old SMTP not the API.

Answer (score 1):

According to [NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/util/Lists when setting up oauth2 on app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817564/noclassdeffounderror-com-google-api-client-util-lists-when-setting-up-oauth2-on),

your

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential
```

error implies that you're missing a dependency in your class path.

But on the other hand your Authentication error may just be a server error because your token is old and you just need to resubmit a new one. See if [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/google-account-integration-in-android-login-with-gmail.html) helps you at all. Its a bit aged (written in 2013), but maybe some of the comments can help.