# Access user mails via Gmail on Android

Tags: android, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to access sent mails with gmail on an android app.
I tried to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) but I don't understand how to get the Gmail API instance.

I also found two ways to connect: the gmail API one and Google Sign-In.

What's the difference between them and which one should I use ?
Is this the way to access user's mails with my app ?

Comment: If you want their emails, the gmail API.  Google Sign-In is about using google for authentication.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan ! What do I have to use then in order to get the mails ? I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) to connect with the gmail API.

Answer (score 0):

**What's the difference between them and which one should I use ? Is this the way to access user's mails with my app ?**

[Google Sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) is good for authentication purposes for your app. It does the heavy-lifting for you so you don't have to worry about authentication implementations.

However, if you intend to make calls to Gmail APIs like the [Users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) you've mentioned, Google Sign-in will not be enough. Components like authorization and scopes are added to the picture. 
So in your case, you need to start with the [Gmail Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) as it details the steps you need to make successful calls.