# How to use Gmail API in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gmail-api

I'm currently at a loss about how to use Gmail API in Android Studio. Can someone enlighten me about how to do it? I've searched around but there's just no specific tutorial/documentation about it. As far as the Gmail API quickstart goes, it doesn't explain well about how to use it in building android app. I'm new to android development and want to learn more about it, so please spare me. Thanks.

Comment: The Gmail API is a Restful API. The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides. If you are looking for a step by step tutorial, you may be jumping the gun a bit. If you don't know how to consume a REST API in Android, you need to learn that first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the new Gmail API from my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686631/how-to-access-the-new-gmail-api-from-my-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Get data from the internet](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-compose-unit-5-pathway-1) course is the best to start, there are other concepts I would suggest you to get familiar with, these are technically optional but would definitely be helpful, here are some suggestions:

- [What is rest](https://restfulapi.net/)
- [Gmail API quotas (limits)](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota)
- [General Google API quotas](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quotas)
- [Gmail limits](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839)
- And most importantly, [the full Android developer training](https://developer.android.com/courses)

Hope this helps!